# Downloading Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, downloads

How do I download Google Chrome on Ubuntu 17.04?

I hit download on the Google website, and in my files it shows up as a package called google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

When I click on it, it brings up google-chrome-stable from Ubuntu software, and nothing happens when I hit install. (I have tried restarting my computer).

Is there another way to download it?

Comment: Yes, and then just click install. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Oh oops haha and I hit install, and nothing happens

Comment: You can install it with the gdebi installer.

Comment: As above, but you'd have to install GDebi first. The default software center should work as well but you need to install the updates first. Actually you should fully update you system *before* installing software.

Answer (score 1):

What I typically do is go to the Ubuntu Store and get Gdebi Package Installer. This makes everything easier for what you want. After that, I take the package you downloaded, right click and tell it to open with Gdebi. After that I hit "install" and let the magic happen. The good thing about this method is later if you keep Gdebi and you come across a package you need/want to install but there isn't a version in apt or a repository you can add it makes things super easy.

Comment: Thank you! I installed Gdebi, however when I opened the package with Gdebi, it said that it was already installed, and gave me the option to reinstall. I clicked that, and it reinstalled chrome, so I clicked on the package again, and it brought up the google-chrome-stable in ubuntu software again

Comment: if it is already installed, then try going to your terminal and typing `google-chrome` if that doesn't work, go to your search and look for it. Typing `google-chrome` is SUPPOSED to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your method doesn't work, here is an alternative method to install Google Chrome.
Save the .deb file in the Downloads folder, then Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open the terminal and type

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

After typing your admin password, then type

```
sudo apt install -f
```

to install any dependencies, and Google Chrome will be installed.

Comment: Hmm after I typed the second command, it said this: <Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 95 not upgraded.>

Comment: Sorry I'm so stupid, but does that mean it downloaded? If so, where do I find it?

Comment: @Aurora If it says in GDebi it's already installed then it is. Stop there! Search for Chrome like any other software. Unrelated: Again, fully update you system (95 not upgraded, not good).

Comment: What is wrong with this answer? Why downvotes and delete votes?

Comment: @Aurora you need to run sudo apt-get upgrade to upgrade all 95 packages. You can launch Google chrome from the terminal by running google-chrome or launch it like any other program.